# Show empty Commit Message on commit in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea

Is it possible to have empty text in `Commit Message` text input in Android Studio? I don't want to see there previous commit message, because usually I have to delete it and write another message.

Additionally: is it possible to disable Commit button, if commit message is empty?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both options are available in *Settings > Version Control > Commit Dialog*.

Select "Clear initial commit message" to have the commit dialog open without the previous message showing.

There is not a way to have the commit button be disabled when there is a blank commit message. However the "Force non-empty check-in comments" setting will affect how a blank commit message is handled.

- If "Force non-empty commit comments" is unchecked, the commit fails when there is an empty message. The commit dialog closes and you are notified of the failure (Mine is a sticky balloon, but I can't remember if it being sticky is the default of it I configured it as such in *Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Notifications > "VCS Important Messages"*) 
  [image]
- If the "Force non-empty commit comments" is checked, when you try to commit with an empty message, you get a "Are you sure" dialog (which unfortunately defaults to "Yes" being selected"):
  [image: Are you sure dialog]

**Note that when you make these changes, they only apply to the current project.** To change the behavior for all future new projects, make the changes in *File > Other Settings > Version Control > Confirmation*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I've created [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10966-clear-vcs-message-on-commit), which deletes commit message only when you perform a successful commit. So, if you close commit window without committing and reopen it, whatever you typed in message box will be preserved. It works with most Intellij platform - based IDEs (IDEA, Android studio, etc.)